# Datanucleus fails to load enhanced classes (GAE)

Tags: google-app-engine, datanucleus

I've been fighting with DN/GAE issue for 2 days now. I use GAE SDK 1.7.0 upgraded to DN v2, GWT SDK 2.4.0, Eclipse (Indigo).

1. I run the enhancer on my Service class:
   21:24:19,468 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Enhancer] - Enhance of class "bookit.shared.Service" starting ...
   21:24:19,468 INFO  [DataNucleus.Enhancer] - Class "bookit.shared.Service" is already enhanced.
   21:24:19,468 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Enhancer] - Enhance of class "bookit.shared.Service" completed
2. There is NO other copy of bookit.shared.Service.class anywhere, just under ../WAR/WEB-INF/classes/bookit/shared/Service.class. It is indeed enhanced OK (non-enhanced size is 7KB, enhanced - 12KB).
3. I start my GWT app, and on the server side I keep getting:
   org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusFatalUserException: No meta data for bookit.shared.Service.  Perhaps you need to run the enhancer on this class?
   at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:498)
4. I turned DN debug mode ON (log4j.category.DataNucleus=DEBUG, A1), however I don't see anything useful other than the message above.

**QUESTION: why is DN not seeing the class (bookit.shared.Service) as enhanced at runtime - it does load it and it is in fact enhanced (I peeked via the debugger), but it thinks it is NOT enhanced at the query compilation step, as the metadata doesn't seem to be loaded (my classes are marked for DN purposes using JDO annotations, not meta files).**

(org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusFatalUserException: No meta data for bookit.shared.Service.  Perhaps you need to run the enhancer on this class?
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery.compile(DatastoreQuery.java:205))

Comment: The log tells you when metadata is loaded, and if it isn't loaded for that class (because it encounters it without any in some class loader) then it throws an exception. i.e if it says there is no metadata then there isn't in what it has presented to it

Comment: I see very little in Metadata logger though: 
13:20:58,972 DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - MetaDataManager : Input=(XML,Annotations), XML-Validation=false, XML-Suffices=(persistence=*.jdo, orm=orm, query=*.jdoquery), JDO-listener=true
13:20:58,972 DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - MetaDataManager : Input=(XML,Annotations), XML-Validation=false, XML-Suffices=(persistence=*.jdo, orm=orm, query=*.jdoquery), JDO-listener=true
DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Registering listener for metadata initialisation
DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Registering listener for metadata initialisation

Comment: I fixed it, finally! I re-followed the steps in "Upgrading to v2 DN", and it looks like there was some versioning issue - when both enhancing and runtime DN jars were exactly as in the steps, it started working, but before it just quietly failed to register metadata.